# Showing color from ternary operator

Tags: php, css, conditional-operator

[image: See here]I am trying to show a color if my ternary operator comes back as true and another one if it comes back as false. The operator is working but one thing is off. The code inside of the double quotes shows instead of the actual color itself. Anyone know how to fix this ?

```
$msg .= ($row['opened'] == '0') ? "background-color: #DDEDFF;" : "background-color: #000000;";
```

[image: Condition is true]

[image: Condition is false]

### EDIT!!! - These are the only times my `$msg` variable shows up

```
public function getLatestMessage ($userLoggedIn, $user2) {

    $query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT body, user_to, opened, date FROM messages WHERE 
        user_to = ? AND user_from = ? OR user_to = ? AND user_from = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'); 
    $query->bind_param("ssss", $userLoggedIn, $user2, $user2, $userLoggedIn);
    $query->execute();
    $query_result = $query->get_result();

    $msg = ""; //to hold the message data

    if ($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) { //don't need a while here because we've limited the query to one record

        //Timeframe
        $date_time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $start_date = new DateTime($row['date']); //Time of post
        $end_date = new DateTime($date_time_now); //Current time
        $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date); //Difference between dates 
        if($interval->y >= 1) {
            if($interval->y == 1)
                $time_message = $interval->y . "yr"; //1 year ago
            else 
                $time_message = $interval->y . "yrs"; //1+ year ago
        }
        else if ($interval-> m >= 1) {
            if($interval->d == 0) {
                $days = " ago";
            }
            else if($interval->d == 1) {
                $days = $interval->d . "d";
            }
            else {
                $days = $interval->d . "d";
            }

            if($interval->m == 1) {
                $time_message = $interval->m . "month";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->m . "months";
            }

        }
        else if($interval->d >= 1) {
            if($interval->d == 1) {
                $time_message = "Yesterday";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->d . "d ";
            }
        }
        else if($interval->h >= 1) {
            if($interval->h == 1) {
                $time_message = $interval->h . "hr";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->h . "hrs";
            }
        }
        else if($interval->i >= 1) {
            if($interval->i == 1) {
                $time_message = $interval->i . "m";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->i . "m";
            }
        }
        else {
            if($interval->s < 30) {
                $time_message = "Just now";
            }
            else {
                $time_message = $interval->s . " seconds ago";
            }
        }

        $msg .= ($row['user_to'] == $userLoggedIn) ? "They said: " : "You said: ";
        $msg .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $msg .= $body = $row['body'];
        $msg .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $msg .= $time_message ;
        $msg .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        $msg .= ($row['opened'] == '0') ? "background-color: #DDEDFF;" : "background-color: #000000;";
    }

    return $msg;
}
```

Comment: How are you using your  `msg` variable ?

Comment: @Nicolas `$msg = ""; //to hold the message data`

Comment: What Nicolas meant is we can't see where you're **using** that variable. Show that part of the code, too.

Comment: It looks to my like you are appending the litteral string to your message. one options would be to add a `span` tag with a `style` attribute that would containe your color string.

Comment: @Nicolas I tried using a `<p>` tag and it still showed the code. Would span be any different ?

Comment: @BrandonT I'm not sure, we don't have information on **HOW** you use the content of the `msg`. you provided the function, fine but we don't know how you use the function. I suggest you look into the [ask] section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing exactly what you are telling it: outputting a string that says "background-color: ... ".

How would the browser know you want to **style** the text with that color instead of presenting those words to the user?

You need to instead specify for the browser that this is a **style** you are giving it.

Instead of

```php
        $msg .= ($row['opened'] == '0') ? "background-color: #DDEDFF;" : "background-color: #000000;";
```

try something like:

```php
 $color = $row['opened'] == '0' ? "#DDEDFF" : "#000000";
 $msg .= "<span style='background-color:$color'>THE TEXT YOU WANT TO COLORIZE</span>";
```

**COMPLETE EXAMPLE**

```php
<?php

function getLatestMessage($opened) {

    $color = $opened ? "#DDEDFF" : "#000000";
    $msg = "<span style='background-color:$color'>THE TEXT YOU WANT TO COLORIZE</span>";
    return $msg;
}

echo getLatestMessage(true);
echo getLatestMessage(false);

?>
```

Comment: Just tried this also `$color = $row['opened'] == '0' ? "#DDEDFF" : "#000000";
            $msg .= $color;`

Comment: We can't see how you tried to implement it, so it's hard to say what isn't correct.  I've added a complete snippet that you can try, which is tested and works.

Comment: Yes, it does. Go to phpfiddle.org or another sandbox, paste the example in, and hit run.

Comment: Right, and since it works in an isolated example, that shows you have a different problem. But like I said, we can't see how you tried to implement it. Update your question with the new code.

Comment: Ok it works but the thing is it's not text that I want to colorize. Its an entire block. I'll show you above

Comment: See the image above. I want the entire block to be blue if a message is unread or black if it is read

Comment: It's the same principle. Add a wrapper element around the entire block you want to colorize (probably a `div` instead of `span`) and put the `style=` property with the color there instead. i.e. `return "<div style='background-color:$color;">$msg</div>";`

Comment: It still kinda doesn't work. It only shows as black even if the column opened is equal to 0

Comment: I put it in this div

Comment: ` $return_string .= "<a href='messages.php?u=$username'><div class='user_found_messages'
                            style='background-color:$color;' >
                            <img src='" . $user_found_obj->getProfilePic() . 
                            "' style='border-radius: 5px; margin-right: 5px;'> 
                            ". $username ."<br/>".
                            $latest_message_details . "</div></a>";`